# Arrange search using Angular JS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular js . I lkie the angular js filter option. How to apply filter option for following div

```
 <div class="block-parent" ng-app="">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>
```

Example: When user type nick on search box then only `<div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>` is need to show $ other two div is need to hide  . i see this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter  . Please help .

> UPDATE : To do this task without Angular js Please refer
>   [Jquery search using real time input , like Filter option in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458669/jquery-search-using-real-time-input-like-filter-option-in-angular-js)

Comment: your question is showing a bit of misunderstanding of how Angular works.  Angular is able to perform operations on **JavaScript variables**, which may include filtering, sorting, and rendering to HTML.  It ***does not*** perform operations on **HTML** ***directly***.

Comment: could you please suggest a good solution ?

Comment: Aside from using a JavaScript array to hold your data, as Aer0 indicated in his answer?  As I suggested in my previous comment, if you are not manipulating **data**, then Angular is not the right framework to accomplish the task.  And for sure, using a filter against HTML is the wrong approach;  filters are for creating subsets of iteratable content, like arrays, which is why they work good with `ng-repeat`, which is designed to display iteratables.

Comment: which is the other good method ? if angular is not good for this  please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458669/applying-jquery-for-search

Comment: I don't do any work with jquery, I'm afraid, I won't be much help with that question.  However, it seems like that is a duplicate of this question, just with different tags;  that's not going to help you get an answer.  Also, you haven't *really* shown enough code here to understand where your data that is populating the HTML is coming from in the first place;  You have a comment that suggests the data has "1000 of answer" but it's doubtful that that was hand generated;  perhaps the filter should be applied where the data is generated (server maybe?).

Comment: please see the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458669/jquery-search-using-real-time-input-like-filter-option-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat`, combined with `filter`. While you display each item stored in your `$scope`s model through `ng-repeat` you can just filter them by using a input field. A specified model in your input field tied up with a proper filter will do the trick.

Markup

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <div class="block-parent" ng-repeat="answer in answers | filter: search">
    {{ answer }}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.answers = [
    'Nick',
    'Sam',
    'John'
  ]
})
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/mOywdZ)

Comment: thank you for solution friend . But the thing is that i can't make $scope.answers = [
    'Nick',
    'Sam',
    'John'
  ] because there are 1000 of answer in the real html and the html structure is already defined so i can't use this <div class="block-parent" ng-repeat="answer in answers | filter: search">
    {{ answer }}
  </div> also .So please  write other method and keep this method also .

Comment: Why not rewrite the structure? Any other solution, using DOM manipulation, could lead to drastic performance issues. Especially if you use thousands of entries.

Comment: actually your answer is very good . But i want answer like @Sajeetharan did . But in his answer he did a mistake . Could you please help to rewrite it .  First we need to load 3 name . Then if some one type nick or any name if that name is present then need to show that name only