# Jquery search using real time input , like Filter option in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

how to apply filter option for following html code **that will check and display on real time input given.**

```
 <div class="block-parent">
  <input type="text" name="search" class="search">
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>

 </div>
```

Example: When user type nick on search box then only `<div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>` is need to show & other two div is need to hide  .Please anyone can suggest a good method .

> ie creating a search result like
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: What have you done already? Please show us the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added with `oninput` event Its will check and display on **real time input** given. **Case sensitive also**.At the time **string empty.It wont display** anything.Its will **search the each letter of containing in** result

**Update the** answer with
Case sensitive select : [see the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187537/is-there-a-case-insensitive-jquery-contains-selector)

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};

$(document).on('input', '.search',function(event) {
    var text = $(this).val();
     $('.answer').hide();
  
    $('.answer:Contains(' + text+ ')').show();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-parent">
  <input type="text" name="search" class="search">
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, instead of  $(document).on('input', 'input[type=text]' ) we can use class name search ?

Comment: also on the first page load we need to display all 3 names, also there is no input then also we need to display all names

Comment: ya sure , just replace with `$(document).on('input', '.search' )`

Comment: yes, very good answer friend . This is the one i expected . A little change also needed .When type n then we need to display both Nick and John since these two name contain n

Comment: @John see with updated answer.case sensitive selector was added.

Comment: Really thank you friend . This is the one i expected . if you have time could you write method two in which search result is showing first and followed by other . For example when some one search sam then the order of result is sam,nick,john .

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562390/jquery-function-is-not-working-due-to-document-ready

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't use `$('.answer:not(contains(' + text+ '))').hide();`, instead of hiding all items and then showing the matches?

Comment: @MeirCohen ya..but only hiding function is not satisfied all .because it's not showing after the text box empty check this https://fiddle.jshell.net/vj6qeqLf/ . Check the Op comment his asked to display all the content when empty input.

Comment: @MeirCohen For my concept was First  hide then show .

Answer (score 4):

You can check for the div's content using contains and hide/show them respectively

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search").on('change', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('.answer:contains(' + text + ')').show();
    $('.answer:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-parent">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this idea . Could you please make little bit advance so in the feature other can use this answer

Comment: It will work if typing Nick not with nick . Also need to check when user type each letter like Angular js .

Comment: you mean case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Geeky's code, you could just do a case insensitive : contains selector that can do case insensitive check.

```js
$.expr[':'].caseInsensitiveContains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};

$(function() {
  $("#search").on('keyup', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();
    if (text === "") {
      $(".answer").show();
    } else {

      $('.answer:caseInsensitiveContains(' + text + ')').show();
      $('.answer:not(:caseInsensitiveContains(' + text + '))').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-parent">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
  <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>

</div>
```

Comment: the main point is , check and display on real time input given

Comment: also on the first page load we need to display all 3 names, also there is no input then also we need to display all names

Comment: changed the event from change to keyup, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method and check the input value, then show or hide the appropriate divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#search").on('change', function(event) {
        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if(text.length){                
            $('.answer').each(function(){
                if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == text) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else $(this).hide();
            })
        } else $('.answer').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="block-parent">
     <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
     <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(98, 128, 145);">Nick</div>
     <div class="answer block1" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(114, 139, 137);">Sam</div>
     <div class="answer block1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(123, 138, 115);">John</div>
</div>
```

This will search even when case-insensitive

Answer (score -1):

give id to all the div's then try this

then in click event of nick write below code

```
                $('#div2').css("display", "none");
                $('#div3').css("display", "none");
```